# Have lots of Users been Removed recently?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

In the past few days, I've seen a few notifications that "User was removed" in my Achievements list.

Some removed points, some added points.

I assume I would see only a single "User was removed" message per user? So should I conclude that at least 3 users were recently removed for some reason? And if so, is some sort of program going on now to remove users?

Another User removed today. Very odd. I hadn't seen any removals for years. Now four in a few days.

Comment: Joe, you have tons of high-quality posts, so you're probably one of the most likely people to be affected. :-)   (No, I don't know who it was either.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I understand that users get removed. I just hadn't seen it happen for a long while, and was curious that 4 have been removed within a few days. I wasn't blaming anyone, nor did I even think moderators were involved in the process. Just curious. Mostly wondering if something (a removal policy?) had changed recently.

Comment: I didn't think you were blaming anyone; sorry for causing any misunderstanding.  I'm not aware of anything that's changed, but that doesn't mean nothing has.  I'm just confirming what I can rule out -- it isn't something the mods did explicitly.  (And we don't have a way to see what accounts have been deleted recently; if we did that might tell us something.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - thanks! (another user removed today)

Comment: There was a [really big one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328642/162102) this weekend, affecting lots of people across the network.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no program from the moderators' side.  Sometimes users request deletion of their accounts, and there are thresholds above which those requests require human review by a community manager.  This is particularly true for accounts that have voted a lot.

I'm speculating, but I suspect the CMs review requests in batches or on a set schedule, which could lead to several events in proximity.

Each notification reports the reputation change caused by one deleted user.  Moderators aren't privy why users request deletion, nor do we know which users were deleted unless we come across posts that now contain user numbers instead of profile links.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen users removed before. But I've never seen three in close temporal proximity.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere right, sometimes moderators delete spammers or sockpuppets, but they usually don't have substantial (valid) voting histories.  In these cases, it wasn't us.

Comment: There have been a few delays reviewing accounts to check for vote preservation; the highest threshold I've seen for this is around two weeks.